# Dynamic Event to release pallet types with specified ID to the time of a dbase

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use the loop trough my dbase and create_mydynamicevent in MAIN for different process flows. So by means of my dynamic event I will release the type of pallets (id) to specified times which I insert into my source block. Because of that I can use my create_mydynamicevent function for different processes. My question is either what is wrong at the myDE and should I also adapt the create_dynamicevent function in Main?

```
Agent Type: Pallet: agent.typeID = pallet types
n = number of pallets I would like to release to the specified time of the dbase 
flowchart Agent Type = Pallet
```

My Dynamic event and wait block are in my custom flowchart Agent Type "Store_and_Pick"
Main to create the dynamic event:

```
List< Tuple > amounts =selectFrom( tor77_kunde1 ).list();
for( Tuple tup : amounts ) {
    Date today=date();
    Date future=tup.get(tor77_kunde1.picktime);
    long diff = future.getTime() - today.getTime();
    int n =tup.get(tor77_kunde1.n);
    process.create_MyDynamicEvent(diff, MILLISECOND, n);
    process1.create_MyDynamicEvent(diff, MILLISECOND, n);
}
```

[image: dynamicevent]

[image: dbase]

Comment: you didn't say what the problem is, but your code should be for(Pallet p : wait) instead

Comment: @Felipe Thank you it works at beginning but after 5-6 loops it stops and nothing get picked anymore. Do you know why? Is it the "break" why it stops looping trough the function?

Comment: i only see 6 rows in your database... so maybe that's why... or maybe there's nothing in your wait block.. who knows

Comment: The other rows are not attached sry. I will do a new question to show my problem. Thank you!